# Azur web app in a VNet

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-envrmnt

I have a web app that is currently deployed in an App Service Environment. One of the advantages of this is the security offered by the VNet within which the ASE resides.

Unfortunately this is a very expensive option for a low traffic solution (currently costing approx. £1500 a month). Is there an alternative solution that offers the same level of security as the ASE solution, e.g. is it possible to deploy a standard Web App to a VNet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to deploy an Azure web app to a VNET (allowing for 2-way communication) without using App Service Environment (ASE).  If you want your web app to only be available to internal systems, you'd have to rely on IIS ipSecurity config (https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/ipsecurity).

Essentially, whitelist all allowed public IPs (from the systems accessing the website).  This might get difficult to maintain, so you might want to investigate a reverse proxy type solution either deployed in IaaS, or use AppGateway, or use a 3rd party such as incapsula/silverline.

Comment: I don't know why the downvote. But this answer looks good to me and I think an IaaS solution would likely be the best option for me. That said I think maybe switching the entire application over to a service fabric solution might also be viable. Giving me the ability to isolate backend nodes from front-end nodes, while also having full control over VM performance levels.

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no.
A way to do that would be to use [VNet integration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet) of a WebApp. Unfortunately, it doesn't isolate the WebApp from the internet (that can be done via the webconfig). The other problem is that it only allows the webapp to access resources inside the VNet, not vice-versa. For that you would have to allow resources to access WebApp from the internet.

No other way currently.

Answer (score 0):

As it has already been mentioned, Azure Web App cannot be added to your VNET. There is a VNET integration option which allows it to act as a P2S client, however it may not be acceptable in all scenarios. Here are the alternate options:

1. Azure Cloud Services (PaaS)
2. Azure Virtual Machines (IaaS)
3. App Service Environment (Expensive)

I think the best option would be **cloud services** as it can sit inside a VNET and provide some benefits of being a PaaS based service. Refer here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/azure/cloud-services/